# Почему не совпадают результаты HMAC SHA256 для PHP и C#?

Tags: php, c#, алгоритм

Не совпадают хеши полученные на PHP и C#. В чем ошибка? Проблема в алгоритме на C#

Код на PHP:

```
hash_hmac('sha256',$data, $key);
```

Код на C#:

```
//ОСНОВНАЯ ФУНКЦИЯ
   public static string HashHMACHex(string keyHex, string message)
        {
            byte[] hash = HashHMAC(HexDecode(keyHex), StringEncode(message));
            return HashEncode(hash);
        }
        private static byte[] HashHMAC(byte[] key, byte[] message)
        {
            var hash = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(key);
            return hash.ComputeHash(message);
        }
        private static string HashEncode(byte[] hash)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        }
        private static byte[] StringEncode(string text)
        {
            var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            return encoding.GetBytes(text);
        }
        private static byte[] HexDecode(string hex)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                bytes[i] = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            }
            return bytes;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP

```
print strtoupper(hash_hmac("sha256", "message", "key"));
```

Получаем: `6E9EF29B75FFFC5B7ABAE527D58FDADB2FE42E7219011976917343065F58ED4A`

C#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    var keyByte = encoding.GetBytes("key");
    using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
    {
        hmacsha256.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes("message"));

        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", ByteToString(hmacsha256.Hash));
    }
}

static string ByteToString(byte[] buff)
{
    string sbinary = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++)
        sbinary += buff[i].ToString("X2");
    return sbinary;
}
```

Получаем: `6E9EF29B75FFFC5B7ABAE527D58FDADB2FE42E7219011976917343065F58ED4A`

Comment: Я бы только написал `string.Join("", bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")))` вместо `ByteToString`.

Comment: Иногда функции - это хорошо. Даже в сравнении с LINQ ;)

Comment: Далеко не всегда. Если писать код вручную, легко допустить ошибку. Например, `string.Join` уже давно написан и отлажен, и использует `StringBuilder` внутри, не нагружая garbage collector.

Comment: "Далеко не всегда." - Ну, я же и говорю "иногда". В этом случае, на мой взгляд, как раз и хорошо написать повторно используемую протестированную функцию, а не лепить LINQ запросы напрямую. Про `StringBuilder` для этой задачи мы можем поспорить - он не всегда эффективен на маленьких объемах :) Что касается производительности, то сам `Select` и внутренний `foreach` по сравнению с `for` имеет свои накладные расходы...

Comment: Ну, давайте потестируем, чтобы не бросаться предположениями. Вот такой код: http://pastebin.com/4irmQL97 даёт вот такие результаты: http://pastebin.com/wQMkM1wP (32 — размер буфера в вашем случае). (Release mode, запущено из-под командной строки.)